# Telerik MVC UI (Kendo) grid does not filter

Tags: model-view-controller, filter, kendo-ui, telerik, grid

I'm trying to use Telerik UI for ASP.NET MVC (Kendo controls). I've got a grid in one view which loads data correctly, but will not filter. I'm an MVC newb, so the problem is likely my ignorance of basics.

My view contains little more than the following grid. It is populated with data, and even the editing functionality works. Filtering is the problem.

```
@Html.Kendo().Grid(Model).Name("JobsRecurringGridEx").DataSource(d => d.Ajax()
        .Model(m => m.Id(o => o.ID))      
        .Read(r => r.Action("GetJobsRecurringAll", "Home"))
        .Update(r => r.Action("UpdateJobsRecurring", "Home"))
        ).Columns(col =>
        {
            col.Bound(o => o.ID);
            col.Bound(o => o.JOB_NAME);
            col.Bound(o => o.DBID);

            col.Bound(o => o.PARAMETER_1).Hidden(true);
            col.Bound(o => o.PARAMETER_2).Hidden(true);
            col.Bound(o => o.PARAMETER_3).Hidden(true);
            col.Bound(o => o.PARAMETER_4).Hidden(true);
            col.Bound(o => o.PARAMETER_5).Hidden(true);
            col.Bound(o => o.PARAMETER_6).Hidden(true);
            col.Bound(o => o.PARAMETER_7).Hidden(true);
            col.Bound(o => o.PARAMETER_8).Hidden(true);
            col.Bound(o => o.PARAMETER_9).Hidden(true);
            col.Bound(o => o.PARAMETER_10).Hidden(true);

            col.Bound(o => o.START_RUN_DATE_TIME);
            col.Bound(o => o.LAST_RUN_DATE_TIME);
            col.Bound(o => o.NEXT_RUN_DATE_TIME);
            col.Bound(o => o.SEED_RUN_DATE_TIME);
            col.Bound(o => o.RUN_INTERVAL);
            col.Bound(o => o.ACTIVE);
            col.Bound(o => o.PAUSED);
            col.Bound(o => o.CREATED_BY);
            col.Bound(o => o.CREATED_DATE_TIME);
            col.Bound(o => o.CRON_SCHEDULE);
        }).Editable(e => e.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell)).ToolBar(tb => 
         tb.Save()).Pageable().Sortable().Filterable()
```

Comment: What does the implementation of your Read action on the server look like(GetJobsRecurringAll)?  Your grid is configured for ServerOperation so it will make a server request on filtering so your Read action is responsible for filtering the data, either "manually" or by using ToDataSourceResult().

Comment: public ActionResult GetJobsRecurringAll([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest dsRequest)
        {
            List<JobsRecurringViewModel> lstJobs = JobsRecurringViewModel.getJobsRecurringAll();
            return Json(lstJobs);
        }

Comment: I have not figured out from documentation what much of this all means. You say that my grid is configured for server operation. What is it that tells you that? What would it look like if configured for ajax?

Comment: Thanks, Dread Pirate! I have at least now looked closer at the DataSourceRequest, and I see a way through this mess. If you can enlighten me on the use of ToDataSourceResult(), I would be thankful.

Comment: The problem is solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK, your Grid/Datasource is configured with ServerOperation(true).  This is the default unless you specify ServerOperation(false).  Ajax() is not relevant(i.e. Server() is the opposite of Ajax(), not ServerOperation())

This means that when you sort/group/filter your grid, it will make a call to your Read action so that *you* can do the sorting/grouping/filtering on the server and you pass back the appropriate results.  ServerOperation(false) would only call your Read action on the initial load(or refresh) but does the sorting/grouping/filtering in javascript(Kendo does this automatically).

So, *you* are responsible for the filtering of the data. Kendo passes the sort/group/filter criteria to your Read action as the DataSourceRequest parameter, and then you use it against your "all" query to return the requested data.

You are free to do this yourself, but Kendo(UI for MVC) provides the ToDataSourceResult() extension method that will apply a DataSourceRequest object to a List/Collection/Enumerable/Queryable/ etc.

All you need to do is return the ToDataSourceResult() of your lstJobs instead of just the lstJobs(which is your entire list) directly:

```
using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions;

public ActionResult GetJobsRecurringAll([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest dsRequest)
{
    List<JobsRecurringViewModel> lstJobs = JobsRecurringViewModel.getJobsRecurringAll();

    return Json(lstJobs.ToDataSourceResult(dsRequest, ModelState));
}
```